# SwiftUI: Create a custom view that behaves like a SwiftUI List, taking multiple views in a closure and arranging them

Tags: swiftui

I am currently trying to create a custom view in SwiftUI that basically behaves like a SwiftUI List or Form. What I want is to achieve is something like the following:

```
CustomView {
    Text("TBD")
    Text("TBD")
    Image(systemName: "heart")
}
```

The output of this custom view should then be a vertical list of the views that were passed in, plus some additional elements, like dividers. Something like what you would get from the following code:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading) {
    Text("TBD")
    Divider()
    Text("TBD")
    Divider()
    Image(systemName: "heart")
}
```

The problem is that I have no idea how to create a generic view that would take any number of other views and then arrange them in such a way - Im not even sure if it is possible.

If there is anyone around that has experience with creating something like this, I would appreciate any hints or explanations.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? What isn’t working? What research have you done?

Comment: ScrollView + LazyVStack + ForEach... trying to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works for 3 views:

```
struct CustomView: View {
    
    let children: [AnyView]
    
    init<C1: View, C2: View, C3: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> TupleView<(C1, C2, C3)>) {
        self.children = [AnyView(content().value.0),
                         AnyView(content().value.1),
                         AnyView(content().value.2)]
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            children[0]
            Divider()
            children[1]
            Divider()
            children[2]
        }
    }
}
```

I believe you need an `init` for each number of Views you want to support. Read more about this here:

https://forums.swift.org/t/swiftui-viewbuilder-result-is-a-tupleview-how-is-apple-using-it-and-able-to-avoid-turning-things-into-anyview/28181/14